# Pandas Output File not separating into different lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this:

```
with open(str(ssis_txt_file_names_only[a]) + '.dts', 'w', encoding='utf16') as file:

    whatever = whatever.replace("\n","")
    print(whatever)
    file.write(str(whatever))
```

When I do a print(whatever) all of the text appears on 1 line instead of broken up. Do anyone know what might be the cause?

Currently, my output looks like this:

```
>N</IsConnectionProperty>     <Flags> 0</Flags>    </AdapterProperty>    <AdapterProperty>
```

What I want is this:

```
>N<I/IsConnectionProperty>
<Flags> 0</Flags>
</AdapterProperty>
<AdapterProperty>
```

Shouldn't the `\n` be doing this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove the new line character with an empty string? I think you might want to try: `whatever.replace("\t", "\n")`

Comment: are you saying that is what could be the cause?

Comment: I can't say for sure because I dont know the original value of "whatever"

Comment: It's just a bunch of XML

Comment: If you take a ssis package, right click and open up in notepad ++, that's the input that I am putting into pandas df

Comment: The replace function takes the old pattern as the first argument and the new pattern as the second. So `.replace("\n", "")` is effectively removing the new linw

Comment: When I comment that part out and open it up in notepad, the results are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line `whatever = whatever.replace("\n","")` is replacing all linebreaks with nothing, so that's the culprit.

To your issue in the comments, Notepad doesn't recognize `\n` only as a linebreak; it needs the full Windows-style `\r\n`. Chances are if you open it in another editor, you'll see the linebreaks if you comment out the `.replace` line. Alternatively, if you make the line read `whatever = whatever.replace("\n","\r\n")`, it should display as expected in Notepad.